# XSLT: How to call user-defined function given as string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to use XSLT 1.0 with the XML below. It has a function `jr:itext` which I have surrogated by a user-defined function with `exslt`. I could strip `jr:itext()` and call the function explicitly as shown in the example, but it looks ugly and I have other functions in the full version.

How do I `call(func-string)` in XSLT`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa">
  <label ref="jr:itext('calculate_test_output')"/>
</html>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa" 
   xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
     extension-element-prefixes="func" >

    <func:function name="jr:itext">
      <xsl:param name="ref" />
        <func:result select="concat('itext ', $ref)"/>
    </func:function>


    <xsl:template match="/">
       Requested output
      <xsl:value-of select="jr:itext('calculate_test_output')" />,

    Using "call function from string?"
        <xsl:variable name="ref" select="html/label/@ref"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ref"/>
<!--      <xsl:execute-this-function select="$ref" />,-->
   
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html so you could try whether the processor supports `<xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate($ref)" xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"/>`. I have no idea, however, whether any processor supporting EXSLT functions and EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` exposes the functions declared with `func:function` to the XPath context of the `dyn:evaluate` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xsltproc (xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20910, libxslt 10134 and libexslt 820) it works for me to use the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` function to call both XPath 1.0 functions as well as `func:function` defined functions dynamically:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    extension-element-prefixes="func">

    <func:function name="jr:itext">
        <xsl:param name="ref"/>
        <func:result select="concat('itext ', $ref)"/>
    </func:function>

    <xsl:template match="label">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(@ref)" xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when run against (for simplicity of the example I used the elements in no namespace)

```
<html  xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa">
    <label ref="jr:itext('calculate_test_output')"/>
    <label ref="concat('test', ' 1')"/>
</html>
```

outputs

```
<label>itext calculate_test_output</label>
<label>test 1</label>
```

Comment: Works for me with libxsl 1.1.32 (in R-library xslt), fails with Saxon 9.1.0.5. Ok for me as I am using R.